# Word order and inversion in English

Tags: verbs, word-order, inversion

I've read some articles on the rules of word order in English, but still have many questions when it comes to particular situations. For example, do the following sentences sound natural, or I need to place verbs after the subjects?

> This district is famous for its art clubs. **There gather** artists,
> writers, musicians and other people interested in contemporary art and
> culture who want to promote new genres and techniques.
>
> The introduction of the law led to dramatic consequences. **This way
> was established** a new, autocratic, and anti-liberal state where a
> single person could have all military and civil power in their hands
> and where human rights were infringed.

Comment: If you quote text in a question, please provide a reference to the source and, ideally, a link.

Comment: @JavaLatte, these are just figments of my imaginations, but thanks, I'll remember this!

Comment: You may want to consider starting your second example with "in this way".

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan , why? What would be the difference?

Comment: "This state was established [in] this way".  In canonical order, the preposition isn't needed to establish the adverbial role.  "This way was established this state".  With the inversion and without a preposition, we can't determine which constituent is subject and which is complement or modifier.  The more likely interpretation is "this way was established [as] this state", which doesn't seem to match your intention.  Using "in this way" avoids an unintended *garden path*.

Answer (score 1):

These are examples of [literary inversion](https://www.britannica.com/art/inversion-literature), or anastrophe. If you intend to write in a literary style, they are fine, but such inversions are not natural.

Comment: Thank you very much!